# Using 3 different data to output 4th dataframe

Tags: r

I’m having trouble working with 3 different sets of data (df1, df2, vec1) to output a third dataframe df3. I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. In df1, each letter in X1 corresponds to a value in X2. In df2, X3 represents a numerical value found in vec1 and X4 represents a letter or multiple letters from df1$X1. I’m looking to scan the letters found in df2$X4 and see if there is a sequential order of N values determined from df2$X3 in vec1, and then remove any letters that do not fit this criterion.

For example, in df2[1, ], the letters are “A, B, D” and the value is 3. Looking at vec1, the max sequential order that includes the value 3 is “2, 3, 4, 5”, meaning df2[1, 2] should be replaced with “A, D” instead of “A, B, D”.  The final output should look like df3. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c(4, 8, 1, 3))
colnames(df1) <- c("X1", "X2")
df2 <- data.frame(c(3, 21, 27, 34, 35, 46), c("A, B, D", "A, C", NA, "B", "B, D", "C")) 
colnames(df2) <- c("X3", "X4")

vec1 <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 21, 22, 23, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 46)

df3 <- data.frame(c(3, 21, 27, 34, 35, 46), c("A, D", "C", NA, NA, "D", NA))
```

Comment: I didn't get the logic here. Why is "B" removed from 1st row?

Comment: "B" Is removed because the max sequential order in vec1 that includes the number 3 is 4 (i.e. "2, 3, 4, 5" has 4 numbers). If you add "6, 7, 8, 9" to vec1, then "B" would not be dropped since vec1 would include "2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9", which has 8 numbers in sequential order that includes the number 3.

Comment: I think you are trying to perform a `join` upon certain dataset similarities, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how join helps here. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not elegant but it may do what you need it to do.

First, create a list that contains consecutive integers:

```
vec1_seq <- split(vec1, cumsum(c(0, diff(vec1) > 1)))

$`0`
[1] 2 3 4 5

$`1`
[1] 21 22 23

$`2`
[1] 27

$`3`
[1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39

$`4`
[1] 46
```

Then, do the following. Check for `X3` in each element of the list, and determine the length if contained in that element. Then, keep only those letters that meet the length requirement:

```
cbind(df2,
  X5 = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {
    l <- length(unlist(vec1_seq[sapply(seq_along(vec1_seq), function(i) { 
      as.numeric(x[["X3"]]) %in% vec1_seq[[i]] 
      })]))
    toString(na.omit(as.vector(sapply(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x[["X4"]], ","))), function(i) { 
      ifelse(i == df1[["X1"]] & df1[["X2"]] <= l, i, NA)
      }))))
  }))
```

It seems that "C" should remain for row 6; if that is incorrect let me know.

**Output**

```
  X3      X4   X5
1  3 A, B, D A, D
2 21    A, C    C
3 27    <NA>     
4 34       B     
5 35    B, D    D
6 46       C    C
```

Comment: I actually found my own way yesterday using unnest_tokens from the tidytext package to "deaggregate" the df2 and then doing a row by row analysis, but your way is much more elegenant than mine.